# How do I set a case open date and/or close date with a webform?

Tags: webform-civicrm, civicase

We've successfully got Webforms that open or close a case and assign a case role.

However, I can't seem to figure out how to specify a date to close or open the case.  All submissions record the status change as today.

Is there a way to specify a case start and/or end date through the webform other than today?

I've tried adding activities to the form and using those dates, but that creates separate activities on those dates and does not apply the date to the change in case status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so, no. But then, I don't think you can do this through the regular CiviCase UI either.

Perhaps the solution would be to expose the opened and closed dates to the webform as fields? This would require patching webform_civicrm/includes/utils.php to add them under `function wf_crm_get_fields`). If that works for you, please submit a pull-request back :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that Coleman.  In the Civi UI, when you click on Add Case, you can select a Case Start Date.  When you select the Change Case Status activity and assign a date, that date is entered as the closing date of the case.  However, if I try the same approach in a Webform (enable one instance of case processing and one Change Case Status activity in the CiviCRM integration tab) it resolves the case today and shows the activity with the date from the Webform.

Comment: Added case start date, end date and case details to webfom-civicrm utils.php. Pull request is here: [link](https://github.com/colemanw/webform_civicrm/pull/51)